# PowerMock: stub methods from parent class

Tags: java, overriding, powermock, super, stub

I'm using PowerMock and I'd like to know how to keep all behavior of the child class, but stub `super` calls that may be overriden by the child.

Say I have this class:

```
public class A {
    public String someMethod() {
        return "I don't want to see this value";
    }
}
```

and a sub class:

```
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public String someMethod() {
        return super.someMethod() + ", but I want to see this one";
    }
}
```

How do I stub the call to `super.someMethod()`?

I've tried

```
@Test
public void test() {
    B spy = PowerMockito.spy(new B());
    PowerMockito.doReturn("value").when((A)spy).someMethod();

    assertEquals("value, but I want to see this one", spi.someMethod());
}
```

Comment: What's happening in the current test case?

Comment: It's stubbing the subclass's method.

Comment: Seems like this bug :https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/487

Answer (score 6):

You can try suppressing the methods from the Parent class,

```
PowerMockito.suppress(methodsDeclaredIn(A.class));
```

Here's an article on Stubbing, suppressing and replacing with PowerMock that might be of some use.

https://www.jayway.com/2013/03/05/beyond-mocking-with-powermock/

Comment: The `suppress` method is not helpful because I need to return a mocked value. Thank you though.

Comment: How about using PowerMockito.replace() to replace the parents method with one that returns your mocked value?

Comment: @Steve the `replace()` worked for me and I returned a value as it expects an `InvocationHandler` . Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to add `@PrepareForTest({ParentClassToSupress.class})` on your test class. Then you can do as Steve suggests and suppress methods in the parent: `PowerMockito.suppress(methodsDeclaredIn(ParentClassToSupress.class));`

Answer (score 1):

The cast you're attempting is not going to work as you are expecting. However, I think you have a couple of options to get around this, certainly with PowerMockito.

Take a look at this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902979/2356554).

Comment: Yea, so I was trying really hard to find a solution to this because the point of PowerMock is that you shouldn't have to change the structure of your code to make it testable. However, I realized that I need to balance that with the amount of time and effort it takes me to write the tests, so I modified the code to make it easier to test. But thanks for the resource!